# htaccess is not working after upload to apache server

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I finished a website and on my pc it runs perfectly fine with xampp, but from the point when I upload the project to a webspace from 1und1.de the .htaccess file is not working anymore and I get a 500 Internal Server Error. I am not completely into .htaccess files but I needed a file, that redirects every request, even in subdirectorys, to the base index.php file.

This is the code:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond $1 !^(content|core|help|robots\.txt)

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Well, what does the http server's error log file say? No sense in _guessing_ what is up if you can read in there what the actual issue is. Most likely the rewriting module is not loaded, I'd say. But as said: go and read what the issue is.

Comment: Unfortunetly i can't read the error_log with the hosting package i booked. At least i guess it don't works

Comment: The hosting provider certainly offers some form of access. How else should you be able to debug issues and analyse errors?

Comment: Apart from that I wonder a bit about that third condition of yours... What is `$1` meant to be here?

Comment: I don't wrote it myself, i think it should prevent access to the directorys content, core... , but i deleted the $1 and the third RewriteCond and it's still not working

Comment: Nothing you can do without information from the error log file. As said: maybe the rewriting module is not loaded. But there is nothing more we can do here. We cannot magically _guess_ what is wrong.